# How to customize the Header and footer for AmChart generated PDF?

Tags: javascript, angular2-services, amcharts

I'm able to create a PDF which is already predefined in amChart library.

I want to create a header and footer with lines and page number. In my below code I'm just able to display text.

```
'export': {
                    'enabled': true,
                    'header': 'AnyText',
                    'footer': 'Page 1 of 1',
                    'dateFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS',
                    'pageOrigin': false,
                    'fileName': 'Graph',
                    'menu': [{
                        'class': 'export-main',
                        'menu': [
                            'PDF',
                            'PRINT'
                        ]
                    }]
                }
```

How can I customize my header and footer by adding lines and spaces?

I went through the AmChart website but I didn't find any information (maybe I missed it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AmCharts uses [pdfMake](http://pdfmake.org/) under the hood for its PDF export functionality. To override the header and footer, you can pass in a [pdfMake object](https://github.com/amcharts/export#user-content-complete-list-of-available-export-settings), which is the same as the docDefinition object in the [pdfMake documentation](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) to override the layout or other settings such as headers and footers. Headers and footers can be static strings or dynamic functions that return objects with formatting information, e.g

```
'export': {
  'enabled': true,
  'pdfMake': {
    'header': 'AnyText',
    'footer': function(currentPage, pageCount) {
      return {
        text: 'Page ' + currentPage + ' of ' + pageCount,
        alignment: 'center'
      }
    }
  }
  'dateFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS',
  'pageOrigin': false,
  'fileName': 'Graph',
  'menu': [{
    'class': 'export-main',
    'menu': [
      'PDF',
      'PRINT'
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: This will work. I just need to figure out how can i draw lines and date in footer. Thank you.